# Download files to Openshift directory

Tags: download, path, routes, directory, openshift

I am using Openshift to allocate a Java application. This app contains a method that needs to download a xml file inside the project to explore it later.

So, the thing is that I need the path for the directory where I want to download the file.

And that is the trouble, I don't know how to call the path I want.

For example:

String filePath = "webapps/downloads/file.xml";

But Openshift tells me the error: 
/var/lib/openshift/56e18fa***********0029/jbossews/webapps/downloads/file.xml
(No such file or directory)

The structure of my project is:

```html
Project
       src > main
                 java
                 resources
                 webapp
       webapps > downloads
```

I Hope I have explained well. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have the option of including the file in the resources folder and having it deploy with the app? this way, it will be on the classpath and can be grabbed as a resource from the classloader.

Comment: The application is already deployed, so I cannot include the file and then deploy the app. Maybe is impossible to get what I ask.